# Custom taxonomy not showing in url

Tags: woocommerce, permalinks, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I want to two have two main product categories on my site:
1- packages
2- services.

I'd like it to show like this: mywebsite.com/packages/package-name (where 'packages' is the archive and 'package-name' is the product page). And the same for services.

I've tried installing CPT UI (Custom Post Type UI) and the custom taxonomy is already showing in dashboard, but still nothing in the url. The current url is still "mywebsite.com/product-category/product-name".

I also tried installing the plugin Permalink Customizer, that didn't help either.

I also manually toke to custom taxonomy code and pasted it in functions.php but nothing changed.

I'll appreciate if you help me get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

U can change the URL style from "setting -> permalink"
there is 5 style able or otherwise you can write your style 
Mostafa

Comment: Thanks Mostafa. Which option should i exactly use for this purpose?